# cPanel theme cPanel X v2.6.0

Tags: cpanel

I am facing a problem. I am unable to change my cPanel Theme please help me.
Some information:

```
cPanel Version  11.44.1 (build 23) 11.44.1.23
Theme   cPanel X v2.6.0
```

Comment: http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8094/where-can-i-ask-questions-about-web-hosting-control-panels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be done by your hosting provider, if you have access to WHM you can check the feature manager for the disabled features.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this from from "Change Style" in the Preferences box. If you are getting any error you will have to contact your hosting provider. They will check the server logs and will fix this issues for you. Without root access you can not check server logs.

Answer (score 0):

Your web host has likely disabled theme changes in your cPanel. If this is the case, you will not be able to change the theme at all, or at least not without their assistance.

Comment: Oh, and thank you Stack Overflow for dragging an age old question up from the dead for me to answer...

Answer (score 0):

If you have an access to WHM panel then you can simply change theme for your hosting account from modify an account section.

[documentation here..](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Modify+an+Account)

Currently, most of the hosting provider offer this feature to change theme from client end - cPanel.

You can ask your hosting provider support team to enable this feature if it is disable. There is no security issue to enable this feature so they should enable it without any problem.

Thanks,